# Why doesn't a systemd-nspawn server restart after reboot or crash?

Tags: boot, 16.04, systemd, container

I have an otherwise working `systemd-nspawn` managed container (minimal Ubuntu 16.04 from `debootstrap`) but I cannot make it restart when crashed/rebooted.

The unit file is

```
# cat /etc/systemd/nspawn/minec.nspawn

[Exec]
Boot=yes

[Network]
Bridge=minec

[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/sbin/ip link del vb-minec
Restart=always
```

Specifically, I was expecting [`Restart=always`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) to respawn the system if it is powered off or rebooted (from within the container) or otherwise crash.

I was wondering if the reason is not because `systemd` sees a `shutdown`/ `poweroff` as the equivalent of a `systemctl stop`? If this is the case - is there a way to change this behaviour?

Otherwise, is there anything else to setup to have it restart?

Comment: That unit file doesn't seem right. Are you sure you aren't actually using `systemd-nspawn@.service`?

Comment: @Gant: I also tried in the meantime to add `Restart=Always` to the `Services` section of `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service`, and then `systemctl start systemd-nspawn@minec.service` but same thing: a reboot of the machine (from within the machine) did not lead to a restart (by the host). Would you know the right way to setup a container so that it restarts after a reboot (of itself, not of the host)?